# Advice needed for generate a sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a tables like, i don't know  how to form a query like my expected output

temp 5

```
id  empid  date
1    E001   11/7
2    E002   11/7
3    E003   11/7
4    E004   11/7
5    E005   11/7
6    E001   12/7
7    E002   12/7
8    E003   12/7
9    E004   12/7
10   E005   12/7
11   E001   13/7
12   E002   13/7
13   E003   13/7
14   E004   13/7
15   E005   13/7
```

temp6

```
Id  empid date
1   E001   11/7
2   E002   11/7
3   E005   12/7
4   E001   13/7
5   E004   13/7
```

temp 7

```
id  date
1   11/7
2   12/7
3   13/7
```

Output: I am expecting these results

```
id  empid  date

3    E003   11/7
4    E004   11/7
5    E005   11/7
6    E001   12/7
7    E002   12/7
8    E003   12/7
9    E004   12/7


12   E002   13/7
13   E003   13/7

15   E005   13/7
```

How to retrieve values from temp5 with all employees but not in temp6 employee ids wit corresponding date used in temp7.
please advice me.

Comment: Do you mean all employees except those who do figure in temp6?

Comment: Are you `absolutely certain` Table7 only has those 2 fields? (id & date)

Comment: Yes nadeem i need all employees except temp6 employee id on corresponding date

Comment: Yes temp 7 has two fields only

Comment: did you check my answer

Comment: Hi sathis i get duplicate values while i execute your quries

Comment: Now Check it..............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this

```
select t.* from (select temp5.* from temp5 inner join temp7 on 
temp5.da=temp7.da) as t,(select group_concat(empid) as id,
  da from temp6 group by da) as t1 where t.da=t1.da and
 not find_in_set(t.empid,(t1.id));
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aced92/1)